# Access to public and private methods from event handler closure

Tags: javascript, closures, dom-events, private-members

I have a difficulty in understanding, how my current JavaScript code works. I've managed to solve a problem in accessing private object method from event handler closure, but I'd like to know why does it work so.

The code utilizes the well-known module/plugin metaphor:

```
(function(module, $, undefined)
{
  function myPrivateCode(e){ /*...*/ }

  module.myPublicCode = function(e) { /*...*/ }

  module.init = function()
  {
    var that = this;
    $('.clickable').click(function(e)
    {
      if($(e.target).hasClass('classX'))
      {
         that.myPublicCode(e.target); // requires 'that' to work
      }
      else
      {
         // that.
         myPrivateCode(e.target);     // will fail if 'that' uncommented
      }
    });
  }

}(window.module = window.module || {}, jQuery ));
```

In the code I set a click handler which invokes either public or private method. It's perfectly conceivable that we need to pass an object reference into the event handler closure, which is done by `that` local variable. What is strange to me is that `myPrivateCode` does neither require `that` as a refernce, nor fails due to its "privacy". This makes me think that `myPrivateCode` accesses not the appropriate object, and works somehow differently to expected way. Could someone explain what happens? Certainly I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `that` and `myPrivateCode` are available to your event handler through a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). In short, what's going on is that every variable and function you declare inside of another function has access to the outer scope.

`myPublicCode`, on the other hand, is not available through closures, because it's being assigned to your `module` object specifically. So the only way to call it is by using `module.myPublicCode()` (or `that.myPublicCode()` as you did – but you don't actually need `that` there, since `module` is also available).

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `myPrivateCode(e.target);` is running in the context of the anonymous function that you pass as a handler to the `click` function.

For more information, read up on [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

For a simpler example, try out this code:

```
var foo = function () {
    var a = 1;

    return function (b) {
        return a+b;
    }
};

var bar = foo();

bar(1); // 2
```

`bar(1)` will always always gives 2, because `a = 1` was in scope when the function was created. In your case, `a` is your `that` and your handler is the closed function.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fh8d3/

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I know about closures.

Comment: Still unclear to me why does `that` work differently with public and private methods?

Comment: You are adding the `myPublicCode` function as a property of `that` when you write `module.myPublicCode`. in that context, `that === this === module`.